# restricting user to only seeing the lecture in big blue button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bigbluebutton

In Big Blue Button(rails) can we restrict the user to only see the class while the class is being taken in live by the staff? The user should only be able to see, hear and chat with other students. All this is automated and should be default. The users should all be locked that is, they should not be able to unmute themselves. Is there a way to do it? Hints on how to do it, please!